# Use fold to find the mode of any list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a possible way to find the mode from the fold?

Code

`var numbers = listOf(9,3,7,6,6,6,11,11,6,3)`

`var answer = numbers.fold()....`

Output 6

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Grouping`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-grouping.html) with [`eachCount`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-grouping.html):

```
val numbers = listOf(9,3,7,6,6,6,11,11,6,3)
val (mode, _) = numbers.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().maxByOrNull { it.value }!!
println(mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a `MutableMap` of frequencies then find the maximum:

```kotlin
fun <T>mode(list: List<T>): T?
    = list.fold(mutableMapOf<T, Int>()) { map, v ->
        map[v] = (map[v] ?: 0) + 1
        map
    }.maxBy { it.value }?.key
```